# Как перекинуть много фотографий с NestJs в ReactJS

Tags: nestjs

у меня есть код на nest Который ищет фотки с базы данных в папке с фотками на сервере как мне передать эти фотки на фронт енд как файл?

```typescript
@Get('image/:laptopId')
async findImages(@Param('laptopId') laptopId: number, @Res() res: Response) {
    const images = await this.imageRepository.find({ where: { laptopId } });

    if (images.length > 0) {
      const imagePaths = images.map((image) => image.imagePath);
      const fileStreams = imagePaths.map((imagePath) => {
        const filePath = join(__dirname, '../uploaded photos', imagePath);
        return createReadStream(filePath);
      });

      // Установите заголовки ответа для массива изображений
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'); // Измените это на соответствующий MIME-тип, если это не JPEG

      // Отправьте массив потоков файлов в ответ
      fileStreams.forEach((fileStream) => fileStream.pipe(res));
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Изображения не найдены' });
    }
}
```

Comment: наверное, можно завернуть файлы в FormData и отправить такой ответ. но, я думаю, всем будет удобнее если в ответ вы отправите массив image.imagePath и потом запросите эти файлы из файлового хранилища